# Grails filter does not redirect in production mode

Tags: grails, paypal, filter

I have a strange problem with Grails filter.
I am using PayPal plugin and I have a filter for filtering payments as below.

```
after = {
    if(payment && payment.status == org.grails.paypal.Payment.COMPLETE) {                    
    ...
    paypalPayment.shipIt()                  
    redirect(controller:"mycontroller", action:"myaction", id:myid)
    return
    }
}
```

Actually, everything is fine in development mode. But in production mode, it does not redirect the request, and gets an exception as below :

```
Template not found for name [txsummary] and path [/paypal/_txsummary.gsp]. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Template not found for name [txsummary] and path [/paypal/_txsummary.gsp]
```

By the way, I can see that it enters to the method "paypalPayment.shipIt()" from the log file.

Any help is much appreciated
Tuncay